# Cakephp 3 gt, lt, gte and lte issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I got a problem with condition in CakePHP 3. I'm trying to deal with deep associated models and build big queries for search engine.

here the query debbuged:

```sql
SELECT
    Ouvrages.zone_id AS `Ouvrages__zone_id`,
    Ouvrages.parent_id AS `Ouvrages__parent_id`,
    Ouvrages.classe_ouvrage_id AS `Ouvrages__classe_ouvrage_id`,
    Ouvrages.numero AS `Ouvrages__numero`,
    Valeurs.valeur AS `Valeurs__valeur` 
FROM
    ouvrages Ouvrages 
INNER JOIN
    elements Elements 
        ON Ouvrages.id = (
            Elements.ouvrage_id
        ) 
INNER JOIN
    valeurs Valeurs 
        ON Elements.id = (
            Valeurs.element_id
        ) 
INNER JOIN
    caracteristiques Caracteristiques 
        ON Caracteristiques.id = (
            Valeurs.caracteristique_id
        ) 
WHERE
    (
        Ouvrages.zone_id in (
            :c0,:c1,:c2,:c3,:c4,:c5,:c6,:c7,:c8,:c9,:c10,:c11
        ) 
        AND Ouvrages.classe_ouvrage_id = :c12 
        AND Elements.classe_element_id = :c13 
        AND Valeurs.caracteristique_id = :c14 
        AND valeur > :c15
    ) 
GROUP BY
    Valeurs.id
```

if i'm testing it in mysql console it works fine.

but cakephp's ORM doesn't give me the same result. With function `gt` `lt` `gte` or `lte` it doesn't work.

i used `$this->log($query, 'debug')` and configure my app config with new query log file but i got the same result if i have used `debug`:

```
SELECT 
 Ouvrages.zone_id AS `Ouvrages__zone_id`,
 Ouvrages.parent_id AS `Ouvrages__parent_id`,
 Ouvrages.classe_ouvrage_id AS `Ouvrages__classe_ouvrage_id`,
 Ouvrages.numero AS `Ouvrages__numero`, 
 Valeurs.valeur AS `Valeurs__valeur` 
FROM 
 ouvrages Ouvrages 
INNER JOIN 
 elements Elements 
  ON Ouvrages.id = (
   Elements.ouvrage_id
  ) 
INNER JOIN 
 valeurs Valeurs 
  ON Elements.id = (
   Valeurs.element_id
  ) 
INNER JOIN 
  caracteristiques Caracteristiques 
   ON Caracteristiques.id = (
     Valeurs.caracteristique_id
   ) 
WHERE (
 Ouvrages.zone_id in (
  :c0,:c1,:c2,:c3
 ) 
 AND Ouvrages.classe_ouvrage_id = :c4 
 AND Elements.classe_element_id = :c5 
 AND Valeurs.caracteristique_id = :c6 
 AND valeur >= :c7) 
GROUP BY 
 Valeurs.id
```

Thanks to ndm for explanation to debug sql query in AJAX. I configured my connection with log at true and i got this kind of result:

```
WHERE (
 Ouvrages.zone_id in (
  34,35,44,46
 ) 
 AND Ouvrages.classe_ouvrage_id = '60' 
 AND Elements.classe_element_id = '62'
 AND Valeurs.caracteristique_id = '25' 
 AND valeur >= '5')
```

I'm trying to cast those numbers, but i didn't found how yet. A simply `(int)` doesn't work.

Comment: "_Doesn't give me the same result"_ and "_doesn't work_" aren't proper problem descriptons, please be more specific as to what exactly happens/the results look like.

Comment: i'm trying to compare a field "valeur" with a input value. The entity have for valeur 10, and the input value 5. If i'm doing `function ($exp) use ($value) { return $exp->gt('valeur', $value); }` Cakephp ORM give me no result when the debugged sql copy and paste in mysql console works fine. Same if i use litteral like `$query->where(['valeur >' => $value]);`

Comment: To avoid ambiguity I'd suggest that you use `Valeurs.valuer`, altough that shouldn't be the problem here. When trying it in the console, are you using the shown query with the placesholders and insert the values manually, or do you use the query that is output in the DebugKit SQL Log? If it's the former, then please check with DebugKit what the query with the inserted values looks like, and if it returns any results (the `rows` column in the SQL Log table).

Comment: Yeah i'm using the the query with the placeholders. I use PHPStorm to run mysql query it bind automatically placeholders. The problem is i can't check debugkit coz i perform the search in AJAX.

Comment: Then use the [**query logger**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging) to write the queries to a log file, or enable logging in your MySQL server.

Comment: i used `$this->log($query, 'debug')` and configure my app config with new query loag file but i got the same result if i used `debug`:

Comment: Please reread the linked docs, there is no need to log anything manually (you won't get the final queries that way anyways), just enable query logging for your connection and configure a logging adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I understood my mistake. Actually we build a weird `Valeurs` table with a column `value` which is associated to a `caracteristic`. This `value` column is defined as `varchar(255)` but can contain Numeric, String or Date. We know the type of the current value coz we also have a `type` column.

But CakePHP ORM cast automatically every data to string because of the `varchar` definition. We must cast our datas ourself:

```
function ($exp) use ($data) {
    return $exp->{$data['operand']}('valeur', $data['valeur'], 'integer');
};
```